# How to change color of every Even values element in RecyclerView in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

In kotlin I'm fresher please let me know about it

```
//In onBindViewHolder method :
        val context = holder.itemView.context
//Here I want to change background colour so please tell me or comment
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
           holder.binding.root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorAccent))
        } else {
            holder.binding.root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimary))
        }
```

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this one :

```
 if (position % 2 == 1) {
           holder.binding.root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorAccent))
        } else {
            holder.binding.root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimary))
        }
```

It will be executed.